# Looking up value by another value

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2016, lookup

I am running SQL Server 2016 and have the following problem which seems quite basic but I cannot figure it out. I have a table `Prices`, which holds prices of different securities, with columns

```
idTag varchar(12) NOT NULL
ts    datetime2   NOT NULL
price float       NOT NULL
```

I also have another table `Data` with columns `idTag` and `ts`, where tags match exactly, but timestamps don't. I would like to find the corresponding prices for each row of the `Data` table (equivalent to constant interpolation in time).

For example, sample values in `Prices` may be

```
idTag | ts               | price
=================================
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:00 | 100.23
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:05 | 100.34
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:10 | 100.45
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:15 | 100.29
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:20 | 100.31
```

and the sample values of the `Data` table may be

```
idTag | ts
========================
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:01
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:03
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:17
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:18
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:20
```

The expected output would be

```
idTag | ts               | price
=================================
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:01 | 100.23
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:03 | 100.23
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:17 | 100.29
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:18 | 100.29
IBM   | 2020-01-01 13:20 | 100.31
```

---

If the time stamps in both tables would match, I cuold write an `INNER JOIN`, but here, the timestamps don't match. I could also do this in code, e.q. Python or Java, but `Prices` has more than 150 million rows, I would rather not read that in.

Is there a way to do this in SQL?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the latest price for a date in a subquery.

```
select
  idtag, ts,
  (
    select top(1) price
    from prices p
    where p.idtag = d.idtag
    and p.ts <= d.ts
    order by p.ts desc
  ) as price
from data d
order by idtag, ts;
```

(You could also move this subquery to the `FROM` clause and use `CROSS APPLY`).

Recommended index:

```
create index idx on prices(idtag, ts, price);
```

Comment: Thank you, I already have the index :). How would I use `CROSS APPLY` here -- would it be any faster?

Comment: I doubt that would be faster. If I am not mistaken, you just move the subquery: `select d.idtag, d.ts, pp.price from data d cross apply (<subquery>) pp order by d.idtag, d.ts;`.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, use an analytic to copy the next value of ts into the current row then use a ranged predicate:

```
select *
from
 (select *, lead(ts) over(partition by idtag order by ts) as nextts from prices) p 
 inner join data d
 on 
   d.idtag = p.idtag and 
   d.ts >= p.ts and
   d.ts < p.nextts
where 
  idtag = 'IBM'
```

Might take a while to do on hundreds of millions of rows..